# How can I fill all the cells of a column in a table with the same value?

Tags: tables

Could you please tell me how to fill all the cells in the right column with the same value like this: [image: like this]

I hope there's a better way than filling it manually like I did:

```
HS71A & 0.0007827980931204725 & 0.9999019214284385 \\ \cline{1-3}
TMM97 & 0.004044567876981621 & 0.9999019214284385 \\ \cline{1-3}
TIMM29 & 0.00498110739785373 & 0.9999019214284385 \\ \cline{1-3}
ERCC2 & 0.006520573020829945 & 0.9999019214284385 \\ \cline{1-3}
EXD2 & 0.006795388081396309 & 0.9999019214284385\\ \cline{1-3}
```

Comment: You can save it in a macro and use that macro `\newcommand{\fdrbh}{0.9999019214284385}`   and use `\fdrbh` in those cells.

Comment: If the value is never changing, why put it in the table in the first place? Add it to the caption. The FDR--Benjamin--Hochberg number is 0.9999019214284385.

Comment: Yes, it’s better than cmd+c cmd+v all the time but still it’s about filling the cells manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>{...}` can be used in the column specifications to add some stuff at the start of the column. It requires package `array`.

However, the cell in the header row should not contain the number, therefore the column specification is overwritten by `\multicolumn`.

Package `booktabs` is used to get a table layout with nicer lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll>{0.9999019214284385}l}
  \toprule
  \bfseries LFQ(SIn) & \bfseries ANOVA p-value
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries FDR -- Benjamin-Hochberg} \\
  \midrule
  HS71A & 0.0007827980931204725 & \\
  TMM97 & 0.004044567876981621 & \\
  TIMM29 & 0.00498110739785373 & \\
  ERCC2 & 0.006520573020829945 & \\
  EXD2 & 0.006795388081396309 & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Variation with package `siunitx` for aligning (not needed here) and formatting the numbers in the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format=1.21]
  >{0.9999019214284385}S[table-format=1.16]}
  \toprule
  \bfseries LFQ(SIn)
  & {\bfseries ANOVA p-value}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\bfseries FDR -- Benjamin-Hochberg} \\
  \midrule
  HS71A & 0.0007827980931204725 & \\
  TMM97 & 0.004044567876981621 & \\
  TIMM29 & 0.00498110739785373 & \\
  ERCC2 & 0.006520573020829945 & \\
  EXD2 & 0.006795388081396309 & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with siunitx]

Do you really need sixteen significant digits?

Comment: I do need :) Thanks for expanding my knowledge in latex tables!